# How can I change background color of button in SwiftUI?

Tags: button, swiftui

What is the best way to change the button's background color in SwiftUI?

I want to create a tile which is a button with centered Text and rectangular background of some color.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

[image]

You can add a modified directly to the button without any containers (ex: Group)

```
Button(action: {}) {
    Text("Click me!")
}
.padding()
.foregroundColor(.white)
.background(Color.red)
```

Hoping to help someone!

Comment: how come . background(Color("Blue")) doesn't work when you have a color set in the assets folder?!

Answer (score 42):

[image]

```swift
Button("Button Text!") {
   //Action here
}
.background(Color.black)
```

Comment: This one don't compile when button is in a VStack

Comment: How can I apply corner radius ?

Answer (score 37):

If you're using the [.buttonStyle(style:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/buttonstyle(_:)-7qx1) modifier and want to change the background color, use [.tint(tint:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/tint(_:)-23xyq) and not [.background(alignment:content)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/background(alignment:content:)). For example, this is how you can change a [.borderedProminent](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/primitivebuttonstyle/borderedprominent) button style to green:

```
Button("Press Me!") {
    //stuff to do
}
.buttonStyle(.borderedProminent)
.tint(.green)
```

[image: Button screenshot]

Comment: this is for above and  ios 15, below ios 15 .background(Color.black)

Answer (score 11):

```
            Button(action: {self.buttonTapped()}) {
            Text("Button")
                .padding(.all, 12)
                .foregroundColor(.white)
                .background(Color.red)
        }
```

that's how the whole bg is clickable

Comment: this seems strange but it is the right way to customize background color in the button

Answer (score 0):

**SwiftUI color**

From iOS v13 and above, when you work with colors you should take into account Light and Dark mode.

```
.foregroundColor(.red)
.background(.blue)
```

For example .black in dark mode will be invisible(black on black). You can use system colors as a variant. For example `UIColor.label`